# ASP.NET Core and MediatR: Send a request from a handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mediator

Is it possible to send a request from a handler?
I have some business logic like: "When user is created - an empty repository must be created for him".
So I have two requests and two handlers:

```
public class AddUser : IRequest<User> { ... }
public class AddUserHandler : IRequestHandler<AddUser, User> {
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;
  private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
  public AddUserHandler(IMediator mediator, IUserRepository userRepository) {
    _mediator = mediator;
    _userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  public async Task<User> Handler(AddUser request, CancellationToken token) {
    // some logic is here
    var user = _userRepository.Add(request.User);
    // create a repository
    await _mediator.Send(new AddUserRepository(user.Id), token); // EXCEPTION!!!
    return user;
  }
}
```

The exception is:

**Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.**

> at
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
>   at
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>
> MediatR.ServiceFactoryExtensions.GetInstances[T](ServiceFactory
>   factory)    at
>
> MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ServiceFactory
>   serviceFactory)    at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>
> Domain.UseCases.Messages.Users.AddUserHandler.Handle(AddUser
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in 
>   Domain.UseCases\Messages\Users\AddUser.cs:line 43

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but this code is wrong!

```
await _mediator.Send(new AddUserRepository(user.Id), token); //Wrong
```

If you use AddUserRepository, try this

```
public class AddUserRepository: IRequest<...> { ... } //Not best practise
await _mediator.Send(new AddUserRepository());
```

You should investigate CQRS(Command Query Responsibility Segregation). Repositories are not suitable for this use.